# Django returns AnonymousUser despite authenticating earlier

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem where I call the `login()` function within Django and despite the user ID being set in the request session, whenever in another view I call `request.user.is_authenticated` which returns `True`.

My login view:

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer

    def post(self, request):         
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            username = serializer.data.get('username')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')


            # If username is not present in the database at all
            user_exist_query = User.objects.filter(username=username)

            if not user_exist_query.exists():
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Username does not exist"}, status = 401)

            # If username and password match
            user_auth_query = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user_auth_query is not None:
                login(request, user_auth_query)
                return JsonResponse({"message": "Login Successful"}, status = 200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Username and Password combination is incorrect"}, status = 401)
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Bad Request"}, status=400)
```

The other view where authentication actually works:

```
class CheckAuthView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I use this view to protect a route (using React as a frontend). The home page is only accessible to logged in users and whenever I am logged in, I am able to view that page and when I am logged out, a different page is showed therefore proving that here, getting the `request.user` does return an actual user.

The view where there are problems:

```
class CreateClubView(APIView):
    serilizer_class = ClubSerializer
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serilizer_class(data=request.data)

        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():

            clubName = serializer.data.get('name')
            clubDesc = serializer.data.get('description')
            clubLoc = serializer.data.get('location')
            clubEmail = serializer.data.get('email')
            clubContact = serializer.data.get('contact')
            clubWebsite = serializer.data.get('website')
            clubOrganizer = request.session['id']
                        
            queryset = Club.objects.filter(name=clubName)
            if queryset.exists():
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                        
            
            club = Club.objects.create(name=clubName, description=clubDesc, location=clubLoc, 
                                            email=clubEmail, contact=clubContact, website=clubWebsite, organizer=clubOrganizer)
            club.save()

            
            
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Printing `request.user` returns `AnonymousUser` and attempting to access `request.session['id']` yields a KeyError. This shouldn't be the case though because if I logged in earlier (proven by the Response of the API call to login and the fact that I can access the home page).

Also, the React code where I make my API call:

```
        const response: Response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/clubs/create', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(form),
        })
        
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("Club created successfully");
            navigate("/home");
        } else {
            console.log("Club creation failed");
        }
```

What's wrong with my code? Am I misunderstanding how Django sessions work? I have another Django project where I do the same thing and it works there perfectly.

I also tried manually setting the `id` before calling `login()` by doing `request.session['id'] = User.objects.get(username=username).id` - this did not work either.

I saw some solutions relating to Django `settings.py`, I don't believe I'm missing anything?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

Comment: How do you log in? AJAX does not set cookies. So if you log in with an AJAX call, it will not work without passing the cookies.

Comment: I just make an api call to: http://localhost:8000/api/authentication/login, along with the headers (CSRF token and content-type) and form data (using fetch())

Comment: ok, well if you login, it sends back a session cookie, likely you don't send that in the next query. Can you take a look in the network logger (of the browser)?

Comment: In the query of localhost:8000/api/clubs/create, the header only has CSRFToken cookie, but not `sessionid`. Do i need grab `sessionid` and send it along?

Comment: yes, since you log in for that session. That being said, most APIs don't use sessions to login/logout, but work with an authentication header.

Comment: Added `'sessionid': Cookies.get('sessionid') || '',` to the headers but results in a CORS error: `(Reason: header ‘sessionid’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).`

I already have CORS installed in Django and settings.py is updated along with it

Comment: But not as "raw" header, just in the cookies, so ``'Cookies': `sessionid=${Cookies.get('sessionid')}` ``

Comment: That doesnt work.. it says Cookies header is not allowed... not only that but sessionid is undefined despite the Cookie existing in the Storage tab alongside the csrftoken... (looking at it right now).. I just deleted the session cookie to see if logging in would create a new one and it doesnt? Not sure why that would be happening. Is there a problem in LoginView?

Comment: You must use csrf_token in django post requests. But your fetch post request doesn't use that. Plus you should only allow post requests to create model objects. Like `if request.Method='POST'`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it was actually related to CORS and how I was calling my API endpoints. The session ID was not being set after logging in because I was making requests like this:

`http://localhost:8000/api/authentication/login`

After changing it to just:
`/api/authentication/login`, the problem was fixed and the session ID cookie is correctly being set.